# Profile pages throwing 500 error across few sites in the network

Tags: bug, profile-page

When I click on the "profile" tab of a user profile, it leads to 500 error along with the "Oops! Something Bad Happened" error message.

[image]

The issue seems to be present on MSE, MSO, SO and a few other sites.

Comment: It almost looks  the profile pages that are served from cache still work. The ones that are a cache-miss timeout

Comment: @rene Time to create a http://shouldipraisecaching.com

Comment: @rene worth to mention that for a time now, profile pages take longer and longer to load, some even 10 seconds, when the user has lots of activity. Maybe it simply reached a point when the slowness times out.